# Error added to Symfony 3 form element is overwriten/deleted

Tags: php, api, symfony, symfony-forms

I have Symfony form with `PRE_SUBMIT` listener.
The listener checks string format for one field.

```
class TestEntType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('someText', TextType::class, ['error_bubbling' => false]);

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $data = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();
            ...
            if (false === $this->isFormattedCorrectly($data['someText'])) {
                $form->get('someText')
                    ->addError(new FormError('Text format should be...'));
            }
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

If the listener is written this way - form is valid, even if I force adding error every single time.
It seems that error is somewhere overwritten or deleted.

But if I make small change, and convert `$form->get('someText')->addError(..)` to `$form->addError(..)`, form isn't valid any more.
If I dump `(string)$form->getErrors(true)` in the controller, I get `ERROR: Text format should be...`
So, the error isn't lost in this situation.
But the problem is that this error isn't bounded to `someText` field!

This is the controller:

```
class TestEntController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/test-ent", name="test-ent")
     * @Method("POST")
     */
    public function testAction(Request $request)
    {
        $testEnt = new TestEnt();

        $form = $this->createForm(TestEntType::class, $testEnt);

        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        if ($data === null) {
            //...
        }

        $form->submit($data);
        if (!$form->isValid()) {
            // ...throw $this->throwApiProblemValidationException($form);
        }

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($testEnt);
        $em->flush();

        return new JsonResponse($testEnt);
    }
}
```

Has someone idea where error disappears when I bound it to the specific field?
Is possible to bound error to the specific field in `PRE_SUBMIT` form listener?
Is there some smarter way to check is string formatted correctly?

- I was following directions from this SO question [Add error to Symfony 2 form element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419551/add-error-to-symfony-2-form-element)

EDIT: It seems that everything normally works if I listen for `FormEvents:: SUBMIT` event. In that case, error isn't lost.
To figure out what is happening, I'll have to in detail investigate how Symfony form works...

Comment: Why don't you just add an `@Assiert\Callback` to your Entity / Model? ([Link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html)). If it's just string formatting, `@Assert\Regex` could be of use aswell ([Link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It will be helpful for some situation. But, it seems to me that this approach lacks flexibility in cases where there is a need for dynamically manipulate user submitted data (before it is actually submitted to a form).