# Symfony4 - Validate fields based on values of other fields

Tags: forms, symfony, validation, symfony4, multi-step

I am building a very large form with multisteps and some conditional fields and cannot find a good solution for my problem.

For example if field A is "Foo" then field B is shown via Javascript and must be validated via Symfony, otherwise the field must be empty. Is there a Way to do this?

PS:
Is https://github.com/craue/CraueFormFlowBundle a good way to go for complex multistep forms and should I use groups and entities or build it without a class? Whats the best practice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My solution:**

I think you should use [Symfony Form Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html). In events you can do such custom stuff like adding errors, check values in all form, remove and add validators/fields dynamically.

More about form events flow you can read [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html)

Here [Add error to Symfony 2 form element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419551/add-error-to-symfony-2-form-element) you have question howto add error to field from event listener(In symfony 4 it is done similarly)

**My opinion about craue/CraueFormFlowBundle:**

I use `CraueFormFlowBundle` in my projects to create complicated multistep forms. It's useful Bundle and saves a lot of time. I created a lot of forms based on `CraueFormFlowBundle` + `Doctrine entities` in combination with `validation groups` + `symfony form events` - powerful and flexible solution which I can recommend

Comment: Hi, sounds great. I don't need Doctrine entities though, because my data is send to an api endpoint, but non db entities should work the same or not?

Comment: Doctrine has nothing to do with it. You can create simple model(simple PHP class) and it should work

Comment: Ok. Thanks! A last question. Is it possible to generate a form based on a configuration file? For example I have a json file with multiple arrays and fields can I create a form dynamicly? My Entities might be different and the order of the fields might change sometimes.

Comment: This can be problematic because you create a form based on the model. 

I would create several models and apply inheritance for similar entities

Comment: I already feared that. My need is to create a form-builder with a frontend in the future, where I can drag and drop fields, or groups. Maybe this could work: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/without_class.html

Comment: You must try :) Good luck

Comment: @KrzysztofRaciniewski How do you reload your form with Craue to update the form with values it contains ? In my case it only reload when I. go to the next step ... Do you have a EventListener. example using CraueFlow ?