# Symfony form validation from an AJAX render

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, symfony, validation

I'm new to symfony, I render forms throughout a JSON so whenever I click on an icon it shows different forms (to change firstname, lastname...).
I return thoses forms as a JSON :

```
    public function profileSettings()
{
    $user = $this->getUser();

    // Formulaire d'informations concernant le compte

    $formAccountSettings = $this->createForm(AccountSettingsType::class, $user, [
        'userEmail' => $user->getEmail(),
        'userUsername' => $user->getUsername(),
    ]);

    // Formulaire d'informations personnel

    $formPersonnalSettings = $this->createForm(PersonnalSettingsType::class, $user, [
        'userFirstname' => $user->getFirstname(),
        'userLastname' => $user->getLastname(),
    ]);

    // Retour en format JSON des 3 requêtes sous tableau

    return $this->json(
        [
            'formAccountSettingsView' =>
                $this->render('user/_accountSettings.html.twig', [
                    'form' => $formAccountSettings->createView(),
                ]),

            'currentUser' => $user,

            'formPersonnalSettingsView' => $this->render('user/_accountSettings.html.twig', [
                'form' => $formPersonnalSettings->createView(),
            ]),
        ]
    );
}
```

Here is how I display this :

```
    $('#settings-user li').on('click', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/website-skeleton/public/index.php/json/profile",
        success: function (response) {
            if ($(e.target).hasClass('profile')) {
                $('.display').empty().append(
                    `
                           <p id="welcome">Bonjour, <em><strong>${response['currentUser']['username']}</strong></em> vous êtes enregistré sous le nom de <strong>${response['currentUser']['firstname']} ${response['currentUser']['lastname']}</strong>.
                               <br>
                               Votre adresse email est : <strong>${response['currentUser']['email']}</strong>.
                               <br>
                               Pour modifiez vos informations veuillez cliquez sur le menu de navigation.
                           </p>`);
            } else if ($(e.target).hasClass('security')) {
                $('.display').empty().append(response['formAccountSettingsView']['content']);
            } else if ($(e.target).hasClass('informations')) {
                $('.display').empty().append(response['formPersonnalSettingsView']['content'])
            }
        }
    })
});
```

The problem now is that I don't know how to handle thoses forms from another controller and validate it with the constraints I set on my entity **User** this is how I validate :

```
public function editCredentials(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();

    $formPersonnalSettings = $this->createForm(PersonnalSettingsType::class, $user);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        if ($request->request->has('personnal_settings')) {
            if ($formPersonnalSettings->isSubmitted() && $formPersonnalSettings->isValid()) {
                $user->setFirstname($request->request->get('personnal_settings')['firstname']);
                $user->setLastname($request->request->get('personnal_settings')['lastname']);

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();
                $this->addFlash('personnal_success', 'Vos informations personnels ont bien été enregistrées !');
                return $this->redirectToRoute('user_profile');
            }
        }
```

Is that a good method? should I handle everything with ajax ? Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `handlerequest` which automatically sets the values in the form to the entity added to it once the form has been submitted.

```
$form = $this->createCreateForm($entity); // private function to create the form
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($entity);

        $em->flush();
    }
}

return $response;
```

Once handled you just need to return an ok response, or return the form back to the view if something has gone wrong.

If I remember well, the asserts set on the entity are also automatically processed with the `handleRequest()`, it depends on how you declared them.

Yo can also add other errors after the submit, just add them between the `isSumbmitted()` and `isValid()`. [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419551/add-error-to-symfony-2-form-element)

I leave you here some documentation that may help.

[Handle request](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html#request-handling)

[Validation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html)

[Validation in the form itself](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#constraints-in-form-classes)